# Mudblazor System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid

Tags: c#, blazor, mudblazor

I am getting the following error on a mudblazor dialog control. The error is not very useful in debugging, any assistance will be highly appreciated:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Reflection.PropertySetter.CallPropertySetter[GolfReg,List`1](Action`2 setter, Object target, Object value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Reflection.PropertySetter.SetValue(Object target, Object value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Reflection.ComponentProperties.<SetProperties>g__SetProperty|3_0(Object target, PropertySetter writer, String parameterName



var parameters = new DialogParameters();
var playersToEdit = new List<GolfPreReg>();
var partner = PlayingField.Where(p => p.ID == SelectedPlayer.Last().ID && p.GolfDayYear == DateTime.Now.Year).ToList();
playersToEdit.Add(SelectedPlayer.Last());
var options = new MudBlazor.DialogOptions();
if (playersToEdit.Count == 2)
{
    var partnerToAdd = partner.FirstOrDefault(pta => pta.ID != SelectedPlayer.Last().ID);
    playersToEdit.Add(partnerToAdd!);

    options = new MudBlazor.DialogOptions { MaxWidth = MaxWidth.Large };
}
else
{
    options = new MudBlazor.DialogOptions { MaxWidth = MaxWidth.Small };
}
parameters.Add("PlayFieldEdit", playersToEdit);
try
{
    var dialog = await DialogService.Show<GolfReg>("Edit player group", parameters, options).Result;
```

I verified the properties to ensure correct database data types and view model matched with database model. I was expecting the modal dialog to show

Comment: try `var parameters = new DialogParameters<GolfReg>();`

Answer (score 0):

You don't share the code of Dialog but I think you have 2 classes `GolfPreReg` on each file (the page and Dialog). The `GolfPreReg` must be shared to avoid the issue.

Here is the working snippet https://try.mudblazor.com/snippet/QaQRvkENORuQQYhB I use class GolfPreReg in the Dialog class which is from __Main.razor: `@using static Try.UserComponents.__Main;`